# How to connect to SQL Server with JDBC connection from sparklyr with kerberos authentication?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, kerberos, sparklyr

I am having trouble accessing my SQL Server database using Kerberos with a JDBC connection. Note I'm running Linux with Spark version 2.2.0.

I am not specifying anything related to kerberos tickets in my `spark_connect`, as I've heard rstudio server pro may have an overlapping capability, though I am not sure if it applies to this.

My connection looks like:

```
table <- sparklyr::spark_read_jdbc(
  sc, 
  "AMI_DATA_STAG_RES", 
  options = c(list(
    url = paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://", <MY SERVER>), 
    databaseName = "fun_db", 
    dbtable = "fun_tbl", 
    driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    integratedSecurity = "true",
    authenticationScheme = "JavaKerberos"))
  )
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
    Kerberos Login failed: Integrated authentication failed.
    ClientConnectionId:878fa848-91cb-4d78-bd48-6dad88b1e401 
      due to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException 
        (Cannot get any of properties: [user, USER] from con properties not available to garner  authentication information  from the user)
```

I've read solutions on the internet, but I'm not sure what applies to windows and what will work with my Rstudio Server set-up on Redhat.

Any help appreciated. I'm pretty new to the wonderful world of Kerberos.

EDIT: I've updated my spellings (thanks!) and pasted in the new error. If I add into the connection string my username and password then I think it does work, but I want to avoid having to paste in my password.

Adding in just my username yields the error:

```
Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot login with Kerberos principal dzafar, check your credentials. Kerberos Login failed: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:543c9b44-e1e0-4fe8-8510-235a21be2845 due to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException (Cannot get any of properties: [password, PASSWORD] from con properties not available to garner  authentication information from the user)
```

Comment: You have two typos in the property `authenticationSchema`. The correct property is `authenticationScheme` (ends in e, not a) and the value should be `JavaKerberos` (that is `Ke**r**beros`). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 for more information

Comment: thanks @MarkRotteveel! I've updated my question with the new error that comes out. I think I need to add the kerberos ticket to my spark context somehow?